# Haar integral, invariance and matrices

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure, bochner-spaces

Wikipedia says:

One property of a left Haar measure $\mu$ is that, letting $s$ be an element of $G$, the following is valid:

$$\int_G f(sx) d\mu(x) = \int_G f(x) d\mu(x)$$

for any Haar integrable function $f$ on $G$.

How does one generalize this property to $G$ being a locally compact Hausdorff matrix group, i. e. for the [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)?

I have no idea how to show it, since the monotone convergence theorem does not apply for Bochner integrals.
And yes, you can project:
$$proj_{11}\left(\int_G f(sx) d\mu(x) \right) = \int_G proj_{11}(f(sx)) d\mu(x)$$
but this gives us not a Lebesgue integral nor a real-valued argument $x$. In addition, I have no idea where I could find such a proof.

Comment: The space of matrices (square matrices) is not a group under product. The space of invertible matrices is. Now, in general one consider functions $f:G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. It is ok to consider functions form $f:G\rightarrow E$ where $E$ is a vector space. In your setting, the there is no need for Bochner integral since $E$ is finite dimensional (presumably you are considering functions $f$ from the group of invertible matrices into the linear space of matrices.

Comment: Thanks. Let's fix a matrix group, $O(n)$. Do you know where I can find a proof for the invariance of the vector integral under the multiplication with an orthogonal-matrix-valued function (or for an other matrix group)?
Reducing to the scalar case did not work for me, since the matrix multiplication written as matrix components does not seem to satisfy the invariance for scalar integrals: $$\int_{O(n)} proj_{11} (OX) d\mu = \int_{O(n)} \sum_{k = 1}^n (O)_{1k} (X)_{k1} d\mu \overset{!}{=}  \int_{O(n)} (X)_{11}$$, but this equation does not seem to work for me.